Redis socket closed unexpectedly in node but connected in python
I'm encountering an error in Node.js when using the RedisClient class, even though I only create the class instance once. The issue occurs only in Node.js, everything works fine when I use Python or the Redis Stack console.
For context:

I'm running Redis Stack in a Docker container on my local machine.
The same setup works perfectly on my production server (also running Redis Stack in a Docker container).

Any insights?

class RedisClient {
  private static instance: RedisClientType;
  client: RedisClientType;
  constructor() {
    if (!RedisClient.instance) {
      RedisClient.instance = createClient({
        url: ENDPOINT_REDIS,
        database: DB_REDIS,
        disableOfflineQueue: true,
        socket: {
          // timeout: 10000,
          // reconnectStrategy: (retries) =>
          //   Math.min(5000 * Math.pow(2, retries), 60000 * 60),
          tls: false,
        },
      });
      this.client = RedisClient.instance;
      this.connect();
    } else {
      this.client = RedisClient.instance;
    }
  }
  connect() {
    this.client.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Redis Client Error", err);
    });
    this.client.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Redis Client Connected");
    });

    this.client.connect();
  }
}

new RedisClient()


Error
Redis Client Error SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly

